# How to dynamic create service proxy with JAX-WS

Tags: web-services, jax-ws

I have common web service interface on each endpoint applications (server and client).
How can I create port on client side without connecting to server for "the same" wsdl?

I search something what present this pseudocode:

```
MagicProxyFactory proxy = MagicProxyFactory.newInstance(MyServiceInterface.class);

/* then bind service address like that
((BindingProvider)proxy).getRequestContext()
.put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, "http address"); 
*/

MyServiceInterface port = (MyServiceInterface) proxy.getPort();
```

Answer (score 2):

Steps include:

1. Create the Service instance using the Service.create method
   for which you need to know wsdl location, service name, and name space URL of the service.
   e.g.

   URL wsdlLocation = new URL("http://example.org/my.wsdl");
   QName serviceName = new QName("http://example.org/sample", "MyService");
   Service s = Service.create(wsdlLocation, serviceName);
2. Get the service proxy (service port for connecting) using `Service.getPort()` method.
   For this you need to know endpoint implemenattion class name.
   e.g. `MyService port = s.getPort(MyService.class);`

you can now call methods through proxy.

Answer (score 0):

Using Metro? You can't. You need the WSDL to create the proxy. Either bundle the WSDL with your client (preferred) or use a URL from where the WSDL can be downloaded during proxy creation.